# Trimming new line character from a string in java

Tags: java, string, newline, trim

The output of below program:

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(final String[] args){
        String token = "null\n";
        token.trim();
        System.out.println("*");
        System.out.println(token);
        System.out.println("*");
    }
}
```

is:

```
*
null

*
```

However

[How to remove newlines from beginning and end of a string (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7454330/887235)

says otherwise.

What am I missing?

Comment: Strings are immutable ... Read trim documentation

Comment: The accepted answer of the question you're referring to shows the correct usage of trim() btw...

Comment: @All: Sorry people.. my mistake.. please don't downvote! :( :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove newlines from beginning and end of a string (Java)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454330/how-to-remove-newlines-from-beginning-and-end-of-a-string-java)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since `String` is immutable

```
token.trim();
```

doesn't change the underlying value, it returns a new `String` without the leading and ending whitespace characters. You need to replace your reference

```
token = token.trim();
```

Answer (score 13):

Strings are immutable. Change

```
token.trim();
```

to

```
token = token.trim();
```

Comment: `Strings are immutable`,Alone  the answer :)