# To remove HTML Tags

Tags: android, html, string

I would like to remove the tag in my android which is coming from an web response. And I dont want to use `Html.fromHtml` in my `setText()`, as I would not like the text to appear in the next line. Can anyone please suggest me an idea?

Comment: Can you post what have you tried so far or what code do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceAll()` function

ex:

```
html.replaceAll("&amp;","");//remove ampersands
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trim` on the String returned by `Html.fromHtml` for avoiding newline before and after the text.

Source: [How to remove newlines from beginning and end of a string (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454330/how-to-remove-newlines-from-beginning-and-end-of-a-string-java)