# How to append character to a file certain "string" in java

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, filewriter

```
File filename =new File("D:/text.txt");

final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(filename);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();

    if(lineFromFile.contains("-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----") ) { 
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename,true); //the true will append the new data

        fw.append(",");
        fw.write("wirte123");//appends the string to the file
        fw.close();

        System.out.println("I found "  +filename.getName());
        break;
     }
}
```

but for me it is adding after a new line....as shown below 
[image]

Need the output file as below 
[image]

Comment: Your file already contains that line break character. To get your desired result you'd have to remove that one first and then append your string

Comment: probably the new line char is already in original file (edit: as he said)

Comment: Can you guys please suggest me ,how to break the new line char ..?

Comment: @String Get content of whole file and then check the last char and if '\n' or '\r\n' then replace to empty string. After that you can append your content.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454330/how-to-remove-newlines-from-beginning-and-end-of-a-string-java

Answer (score 2):

The original file already contains an ending new line. So if you *append* something to the original file, it will be written after that new line.

What is worse, is that a `Scanner` is a high level object that do not allow you to know the exact position in the file where an internal cursor could be positionned, because internally it reads large buffers (for a certificate file, the whole file is likely to be read at once).

So you should rather use a `RandomAccessFile` and its associated `FileChannel` to record the position of each begin of line, and to truncate the file just before a possible end of line.

Code could become:

```
    RandomAccessFile fw = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "rw");
    FileChannel fc = fw.getChannel();
    long oldpos;
    while (true) {
        oldpos = fc.position();
        final String lineFromFile = fw.readLine();

        if (lineFromFile.contains("-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----")) {
            System.out.println("I found "  +filename.getName());*/
            fc.truncate(oldpos + lineFromFile.length());
            fw.writeBytes(",wirte123");//appends the string to the file
            break;
        }
    }
    fw.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bufferwriter with fileWriter and use append method of buffer writer and it will append to text instead of creating new line.

E.g.

```
 File filename = new File("D:/text.txt");
 FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(filename,true);
 BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
 bufferWritter.append(",wirte123");
 bufferWritter.close();
 fileWritter.close();
```