# How do I cut blank lines from EditText using XML that the unnecessary lines aren't shown in TextView

Tags: android, xml, chat

I have an EditText where I put a message in. Let's say I write a message like "Hi" followed by lot of blank lines, then the ChatBubble wraps in the blank lines as well. How can I remove them without converting the Message Object to a String? Is there a way using XML only?

[image: example]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove newlines from beginning and end of a string (Java)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454330/how-to-remove-newlines-from-beginning-and-end-of-a-string-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could solve your problem by first taking the text that you enter in the `EditText` and save it to a `String` variable, like so:

```
String message = String.valueOf(editText.getText())
```

Then you could simply replace any new lines (or any text that you are looking for) in that `String` variable.

```
newMessage = message.replace("\n", "")
```

Replace the "\n" with whatever you want to replace. Using the `newMessage` variable, create your `ChatBubble` and display the text you want. Hope it helps!

Comment: I think a better approach would be using something like `String trimmedString = message.trim();` . Using this you can remove all the whitespaces from the beginning and from the end of a `String`.

Comment: @Iulian Popescu, That is also a good idea, thanks for the help. Either way works.