# How to remove last line of TextView?

Tags: java, android, textview

I am trying to remove\replace last line of a `TextView`, but **I want a way to do this faster**.
For example I found this:

```
String temp = TextView.getText().toString();
temp.substring(0,temp.lastIndexOf("\n"));
```

But I want to do it faster without copy data from Textview to a string value and dont using `Sting.lastIndexOf` (because its search in a string).

Can some one help me?

**My Question isn't a dupplicate question becuase I want a way without using a string type!!!**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove newlines from beginning and end of a string (Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454330/how-to-remove-newlines-from-beginning-and-end-of-a-string-java)

Comment: So if I understand correctly your current way does work, but you want a simpler alternative? One question: do you want to remove the last line of a String or of the TextView itself? If the first, your method seems fine by me (perhaps put it in a method with a `TextView` as parameter for re-usability). If the second, you currently use `TextView.setText(temp)` I assume? You could perhaps overwrite the `TextView` class and create a method `removeLastLine()` with the code you currently have.

Comment: yes my question is second one , But  I dont want to copy its data to an String

Comment: My Question isn't a dupplicate question becuase I want a way without using a string type

Comment: But why? `TextView` doesn't have a builtin for `removeLastLine()`, so you'll either have to create a child-class with your own implementation overwriting the existing `TextView` and containing an additional `removeLastLine()` which you can use. Or if you are looking for a one-liner without creating a variable for `String temp` for whatever reason, you could use `textView().setText(textView().getText().toString().replaceAll("(.*)\n[^\n]+$", "$1"));` for example.. I just don't understand ***why*** you don't want the `String temp = ...` :S I've voted to close as 'unclear'..

Comment: because my program is very large  and I want a very fast program so when I use `string.replace()`  or `string.lastIndex()` , its search my String and my program run slower.So I want to do it with a better way.

Comment: amir133, I hope you do understand that removing any part of a string involves:  (a) finding that part, and  (b) removing it. So how do you expect to do it without `lastIndex` and `substring`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest overwriting the `TextView` class with your own implementation:

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView{
  // Overwrite any mandatory constructors and methods and just call super

  public void removeLastLine(){
    if(getText() == null) return;
    String currentValue = getText().toString();
    String newValue = currentValue.substring(0, currentValue.lastIndexOf("\n"));
    setText(newValue);
  }
}
```

Now you could use something along the lines of:

```
CustomTextView textView = ...

textView.removeLastLine();
```

---

Alternatively, since you seem to be looking for a one-liner without creating a `String temp` for some reason, you could do this:

```
textView.setText(textView.getText().toString().replaceFirst("(.*)\n[^\n]+$", "$1"));
```

**Regex explanation:**

```pyth
(.*)            # One or more character (as capture group 1)
    \n          # a new-line
      [^\n]     # followed by one or more non new-lines
           $    # at the end of the String

$1              # Replace it with the capture group 1 substring
                # (so the last new-line, and everything after it are removed)
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dYwxC8IwEIV3f8VxOKRWA66Kg0K7iaBujUJsg0bTszSnINLfXlM7ODk87nHvfe@qn3pyLW5tmzvtPay1pfcAoHqcnM3Bs@ZwnndbQBkisePa0jk7gI66GkD/ADaeYQHIF@sVddKKvC0rZxR1Ic77@suzKeX9wbIKIDsSuErSzTaZKcK434kx@KgH/lLLdJ9sf5CsTeV0blJbexYo5ChSlB0VHeIhjnE4xei72Ayatv0A)

Comment: because my program is very large  and I want a very fast program so when I use `string.replace()`  or `string.lastIndex()` , its search my String and my program run slower.So I want to do it with a faster way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public String removeLastParagraph(String s) {
    int index = s.lastIndexOf("\n");
    if (index < 0) {
        return s;
    }
    else {
        return s.substring(0, index);
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
tv.setText(removeLastParagraph(tv.getText().toString().trim());
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `System.getProperty("line.seperator")`  instead of "\n"

```
public void removeLastLine(TextView textView) {
    String temp = textView.getText().toString();
    textView.setText(
        temp.substring(0, temp.lastIndexOf(System.getProperty("line.seperator") )));
}
```

Comment: String are immutable

Comment: @ZUNJAE Well spotted, typo when modifying example code, now fixed.