# Why do i get for an Integer.parseInt(String) an numberformatexception?

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I feel like the solution is very simple but I am right now staring at it for 10 Minutes and i cannot find any errors in my code. Seriously.

Whereas `eventDateStart` is an integer. Integer normally do take 8 characters for string to `int` conversions and i don't see why Java cannot converse it I am like ... ugh??

Code is producing NumberFormatException:

```
String rruleMonthday = "-1";

//where ar rrule is sth like --> RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=29
int firstMonthday = (rrule.indexOf("BYMONTHDAY=") + 11);

try {
rruleMonthday = rrule.substring(firstMonthday, rrule.indexOf(";", firstMonthday));
} catch (Exception ex) {
 rruleMonthday = rrule.substring(firstMonthday, rrule.indexOf("\n", firstMonthday));
}

eventDateStart = eventDateStart.substring(0, 6) + rruleMonthday;

System.out.println("eventDateStart: ." + eventDateStart + ".");


System.out.println("2: " + Integer.parseInt(eventDateStart)); //this Integer.parseInt conversion is printing numberformatexception
```

output:

```
eventDateStart: .20200329.

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20200329"
```

Comment: Where does the value for `eventDateStart` come from? I'd try using a debugger to inspect values instead of `println`

Comment: What is the return value of `eventDateStart.length()`?

Comment: You most likely have unprintable characters in the `20200329`. Post what `System.out.println(eventDateStart.codePoints().mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));` will print.

Comment: : eventDateStart.length(): 9

and @karol: 50,48,50,48,48,51,50,57,13


i dont yet see what the problem could lie at?

Comment: `13` is a carriage return. Try [trimming your string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454330/how-to-remove-newlines-from-beginning-and-end-of-a-string-java)

Comment: .. i have even put an . and couldn't see the new line. Damn

 How could I make java trim it without the new line?

Comment: Thanks this solved my "simple" problem :')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/) the sequence `50,48,50,48,48,51,50,57` is the `20200329` value. In your case it's followed by a carriage return symbol `13`.

Most likely you are using Windows where the line end sequence is `\r\n`. Instead of `\n` use [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator()) to make your code platform independent:

```
} catch (Exception ex) {
    rruleMonthday = rrule.substring(firstMonthday, 
            rrule.indexOf(System.lineSeparator(), firstMonthday));
}
```