# How to split a comma-separated string?

Tags: java, string, split

I have a String with an unknown length that looks something like this

```
"dog, cat, bear, elephant, ..., giraffe"
```

What would be the optimal way to divide this string at the commas so each word could become an element of an ArrayList?

For example

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<Strings>();
// Add the data here so strings.get(0) would be equal to "dog",
// strings.get(1) would be equal to "cat" and so forth.
```

Comment: use method split("spliting char") it splits your string nad method will create string-array with splitted words.

Answer (score 404, accepted):

You could do this:

```
String str = "...";
List<String> elephantList = Arrays.asList(str.split(","));
```

Basically the [`.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method will split the string according to (in this case) delimiter you are passing and will return an array of strings.

However, you seem to be after a List of Strings rather than an array, so the array must be turned into a list by using the [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) utility. Just as an FYI you could also do something like so:

```
String str = "...";
ArrayList<String> elephantList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(str.split(","));
```

But it is usually better practice to program to an interface rather than to an actual concrete implementation, so I would recommend the 1st option.

Comment: @JamesFazio: The `.split` method is one of the most handy methods in the String class, I would recommend you check out the link for the JavaDocs I have included in my answer ;).

Comment: Keep in mind this won't trim the values so strings.get(1) will be " cat" not "cat"

Comment: `str.split` accepts regex so you can use `str.split(",[ ]*");` so you remove commas and spaces after commas.

Comment: A comma delimited file (csv) might have a a comma in quotes, meaning it's not a delimiter. In this case Split will not work.

Comment: The second option requires as cast to `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: If you need to keep empty entries (eg.for consistent array length) use split(",",-1) as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602062/java-string-split-removed-empty-values

Comment: In this case you have to be careful with empty substring. That is ";;;".split(";") will produce empty array

Comment: What if you would like to store the resulting items in a set rather than a list?

Comment: @MosesKirathe: You should be able to do something like: `new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));`.

Comment: How to get rid of empty entries in this?

Answer (score 174):

Well, you want to **split**, right?

```
String animals = "dog, cat, bear, elephant, giraffe";

String[] animalsArray = animals.split(",");
```

If you want to additionally get rid of whitespaces around items:

```
String[] animalsArray = animals.split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

Comment: Yes that is part of the solution. The OP seems to be after a List of Strings, not an array.

Comment: @npinti: yep, +1 to you, you were faster and I didn't want to copy your `Arrays.asList()` idiom.

Comment: I kept thinking for 10 hours, then searched SO. didn't know that it is so easy to .split();

Comment: What if you would like to store the resulting split items in a set rather than an in an Array?

Answer (score 44):

You can split it and make an array then access like an array:

```
String names = "prappo,prince";
String[] namesList = names.split(",");
```

You can access it with its indexes

```
String name1 = namesList [0];
String name2 = namesList [1];
```

or using a loop

```
for(String name : namesList){
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Answer (score 22):

A small improvement: above solutions will not remove leading or trailing spaces in the actual String. It's better to call trim before calling split.
Instead of this,

```
 String[] animalsArray = animals.split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

use

```
 String[] animalsArray = animals.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

Comment: for ur second line, if we use trim() then we don't need space split like `("\\s*,\\s*")` just use `(",");` this will results same.

Comment: I'm not sure of that @WIZARD because trim remove only the left and right space of the string, but not the space in it. So the `trim("  string, with , space    ")` will be `"string, with , space"`.

Comment: @ThomasLeduc if string is like this `"dog, cat, bear, elephant, giraffe"` then no need of `trim()` and in ur case if use `trim()` then out put will be  `"string,with,space"` not this `"string, with , space"`

Comment: `trim()` will remove all spaces not just left and right space of string

Comment: Do you test it ? because I've just wrote a program java and the string  `"        string, with , space    ".trim()` return `"string, with , space"`. Like javadoc says : returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.
You are wrong and @user872858 is right.

Answer (score 3):

First you can split names like this

```
String animals = "dog, cat, bear, elephant,giraffe";

String animals_list[] = animals.split(",");
```

to Access your animals

```
String animal1 = animals_list[0];
String animal2 = animals_list[1];
String animal3 = animals_list[2];
String animal4 = animals_list[3];
```

And also you want to remove white spaces and comma around animal names

```
String animals_list[] = animals.split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, using the [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library, you'd do:   `Splitter.on(",").split(“dog,cat,fox”)`

Another example:

```
String animals = "dog,cat, bear,elephant , giraffe ,  zebra  ,walrus";
List<String> l = Lists.newArrayList(Splitter.on(",").trimResults().split(animals));
// -> [dog, cat, bear, elephant, giraffe, zebra, walrus]
```

`Splitter.split()` returns an Iterable, so if you need a List, wrap it in `Lists.newArrayList()` as above. Otherwise just go with the Iterable, for example:

```
for (String animal : Splitter.on(",").trimResults().split(animals)) {
    // ...
}
```

Note how `trimResults()` handles all your trimming needs without having to [tweak regexes for corner cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20518948/56285), as with `String.split()`.

If your project uses Guava already, this should be your preferred solution. See Splitter documentation in [Guava User Guide](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter) or the [javadocs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) for more configuration options.

Answer (score 2):

Can try with this worked for me

```
 sg = sg.replaceAll(", $", "");
```

or else

```
if (sg.endsWith(",")) {
                    sg = sg.substring(0, sg.length() - 1);
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

in build.gradle add Guava

```
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '27.0-jre'
```

and then

```
    public static List<String> splitByComma(String str) {
    Iterable<String> split = Splitter.on(",")
            .omitEmptyStrings()
            .trimResults()
            .split(str);
    return Lists.newArrayList(split);
    }

    public static String joinWithComma(Set<String> words) {
        return Joiner.on(", ").skipNulls().join(words);
    }
```

enjoy :)

Comment: you can use Splitter.splitToList which returns an unmodifiable List

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin,

```
val stringArray = commasString.replace(", ", ",").split(",")
```

where `stringArray` is `List<String>` and `commasString` is `String` with commas and spaces

Answer (score 1):

Easy and Short solution:-

> String str="test 1 ,test 2  , test 3";
>
> ```
> List<String> elementList = Arrays.asList(str.replaceAll("\\s*,\\s*", ",").split(","));
> ```
>
> Output=["test 1","test 2","test 3"]

It will working for all cases.

Thanks me later :-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: simple and clean answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove all white spaces and create an *fixed-size* or *immutable* List (See `asList` [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)))

```
final String str = "dog, cat, bear, elephant, ..., giraffe";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str.replaceAll("\\s", "").split(","));
// result: [dog, cat, bear, elephant, ..., giraffe]
```

It is possible to also use `replaceAll(\\s+", "")` but maximum efficiency depends on the use case. (see @GurselKoca [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455794/removing-whitespace-from-strings-in-java#answer-5455809) to **Removing whitespace from strings in Java**)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
String animals = "dog, cat, bear, elephant, giraffe";

List<String> animalList = Arrays.asList(animals.split(","));
```

Also, you'd include the libs:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays; 
import java.util.List;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
        List<String> splitString = (List<String>) Arrays.asList(jobtype.split(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is an easy way to split string by comma,**

```
import java.util.*;

public class SeparatedByComma{
public static void main(String []args){
     String listOfStates = "Hasalak, Mahiyanganaya, Dambarawa, Colombo";
     List<String> stateList = Arrays.asList(listOfStates.split("\\,"));
     System.out.println(stateList);
 }
}
```

Comment: This code I used for JDK. And if You need to print the array. use System.out.println

Answer (score 0):

"Old school" (JDK1.0) *java.util* Class *StringTokenizer* :

**StringTokenizer**(**String** str, **String** delim)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Tokenizer {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                String str = "dog, cat, bear, elephant, ..., giraffe";
                StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");

                List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

                while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                        // if need to trim spaces .trim() or use delim like ", "
                        String token = tokenizer.nextToken().trim();
                        strings.add(token);
                }
                // test output
                strings.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
}
```

NB:
***StringTokenizer*** is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the ***split*** method of String or the ***java.util.regex*** package instead.

Example:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
...
// Recommended method<?>
Pattern commaPattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*,\\s*");
String[] words = commaPattern.split(str);
List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(words));

// test output
wordList.forEach(System.out::println);
...
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a function called `replaceAll()` that can remove all whitespaces by replacing them with whatever you want. As an example

```
String str="  15. 9 4;16.0 1"
String firstAndSecond[]=str.replaceAll("\\s","").split(";");
System.out.println("First:"+firstAndSecond[0]+", Second:"+firstAndSecond[1]);
```

will give you:

```
First:15.94, Second:16.01
```