# How to put Java String to array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a java String of a list of numbers with comma separated and i want to put this into an array only the numbers. How can i achieve this?

```
String result=",17,18,19,";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [splitting a comma separated string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631715/splitting-a-comma-separated-string) and [Java: How to convert comma separated String to ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488643/java-how-to-convert-comma-separated-string-to-arraylist)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First remove leading commas:

```
result = result.replaceFirst("^,", "");
```

If you don't do the above step, then you will end up with leading empty elements of your array. Lastly split the String by commas (note, this will not result in any *trailing* empty elements):

```
String[] arr = result.split(",");
```

One liner:

```
String[] arr = result.replaceFirst("^,", "").split(",");
```

Comment: @PaulVargas: No, this is Java

Comment: The calls to `replaceFirst` have unnecessary `'/'`s in the pattern and are missing a replacement string.

Comment: tskuzzy your answer is exactly correct. When i used other methods the length of the array is not properly out put. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
String[] myArray = result.split(",");
```

This returns an array separated by your argument value, which can be a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

Try `split()`

Assuming this as a fixed format,

```
String result=",17,18,19,";
String[] resultarray= result.substring(1,result.length()).split(",");
for (String string : resultarray) {
    System.out.println(string);
}

//output : 17 18 19
```

That [split() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) returns

> the array of strings computed by splitting this string around matches of the given regular expression

Comment: wat about first comma , ur codse w'll result into blank space for 1st index

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this :

```
String result ="1,2,3,4";
String[] nums = result.spilt(","); // num[0]=1 , num[1] = 2 and so on..
```

Comment: wat about first comma , ur codse w'll result into blank space for 1st index

Comment: @user123 I just gave an example how to use spilt function.

Comment: question is String result=",17,18,19," not String result="17,18,19," first char is comma, for asked question split(",") will give num[1]=17 and num[0]=blank space.question is about to truncating first comma also

Answer (score 1):

```
String result=",17,18,19,";
String[] resultArray = result.split(",");
System.out.printf("Elements in the array are: ");
    for(String resultArr:resultArray)
    {
        System.out.println(resultArr);
    }
```