# Replacing last character given in a string

Tags: java, regex, string, match

I have a string in java:

```
String text = "A, B, C, D, ";
```

How I can to get `"A, B, C and D"`?

I have "A, B, C, D" as well: text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf(",")), but how do I get the result I want?

Thanks!!!

Comment: `How do I can to get` made me chuckle. Is this a `String` literal? Or are you generating the `String` from some `Iterable`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [splitting a comma separated string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631715/splitting-a-comma-separated-string)

Comment: My string is complicated, but this is the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
text = text.replaceAll(", (\\w+), $", " and $1");
```

`replaceAll` uses [regex](http://regular-expressions.info) as first parameter and can use parts matched by this regex in replacement via `$x` where `x` refers to part matched with [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) number `x` (to put it shortly groups are parts or regex from parenthesis).

So this regex will match `, oneOrMoreCharacters,` which is right before the end of string which in regex can be represented with `$`.

DEMO:

```
System.out.println("A, B, C, D, ".replaceAll(", (\\w+), $", " and $1"));
```

output: `A, B, C and D`

---

EDIT

If your `D` part can also contain non alphanumeric characters then instead of `\\w` use `[^,]` which represents all characters except `,`. So try with

```
text = text.replaceAll(", ([^,]+), $", " and $1");
```

Comment: Your code work in this example, but when the elments contains space this not work, example: "First word, second word, other word, etc, "..replaceAll(", (\\w+), $", " and $1") give as result the same input. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @victorpacheco3107 then instead of `\\w` which represents only alphanumeric characters you can use `[^,]` which represents all characters except comma.

Comment: @victorpacheco3107 Could you test my updated answer?

Comment: @victorpacheco3107 Glad you like it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
"A, B, C, D, ".replace(", D, ", " and D");
```

Comment: The string is dinamyc :/

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

1. Remove the last ","
   So you will be left with A, B, C, D
2. Replace the last "," with " and "
   The result is A, B, C and D.

You can do this using StringBuilder:

```
String myStr = "A, B, C, D,";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(myStr);
builder.replace(builder.lastIndexOf(","), builder.lastIndexOf(",")+1, "");
builder.replace(builder.lastIndexOf(","), builder.lastIndexOf(",")+1, " and ");
String result = builder.toString();

System.out.println(result);//Should print A, B, C and D
```

I have not tested this code. But you get the idea.

Comment: How replace the last ","?

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "A, B, C, D, ";
String[] split=text.split(",");
String ans="";
for(int i=0;i<split.length;i++){
    if(i==split.length-2){
        ans+= "and "+ split[i].replace(" ","");
        break;
    }
    if(i>0){
      ans+=", ";
    }
    ans+=split[i];
}

System.out.println(ans); // what you wanted
```

Comment: As OP claims real values under `D` can be even words separated with space so this solution will generate `A,  B,  Cand word1word2word3` for input as `"A, B, C, word1 word2 word3, "`.

Comment: this code is not splitted by spaces. read the answer before you write comments.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using code like

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
String text = "";
for (String token : list) {
    text += token + ", ";
}
System.out.println(text);
```

to generate your `text` value.

Instead, write the first value. Then write everything but the last value. Then write the last value with the `and` prepended.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
String text = "";
if (!list.isEmpty()) {
    text += list.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        text += ", " + list.get(i);
    }
    if (list.size() > 1)
        text += " and " + list.get(list.size() - 1);
}
System.out.println(text);
```

Obviously, use a `StringBuilder` if appropriate. The above prints

```
A, B, C and D
```

The beauty of this is that it works with any number of values, doing the least possible number of checks for lengths and tokens remaining. With a single element, it would print only that value

```
A
```

With two elements (A and B), it would print

```
A and B
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```
String text = "A, B, C, D, ";
String[] a=text.split(",");
int i=a.length-1;
    while(i>=0 && (a[i]==null || a[i].trim().isEmpty()))
        i--;

System.out.println(a[i]);
```