# Splitting a string ignoring whitespace

Tags: java, string, split

I am splitting a string with a comma as a delimeter using `String.split()` function in java.

**Input**

```
1,1,87 gandhi road,600005
```

**Output:**

```
1
1
87
```

The code stops at whitespace. How do I get it to work ?

Comment: How about taking a look at the documentation first? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String) and also doing a few google searches? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631715/splitting-a-comma-separated-string And also looking at the tour page? http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll need to see your code before we can begin troubleshooting. However, the following code should work just fine:

```
String address = "1,1,87 gandhi road,600005";

String[] stringArray = address.split(",");

for(String str : stringArray)
{
    // Do something with str.
}
```

Comment: `string` is still misspelled :P.

Comment: Got my language syntax mixed up. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I should sleep. I'm clearly not thinking right. :P

Comment: What happens here is that after 87 it stops reading since a blank space occurs and I have no idea why

Comment: @SidhanthSur then we'll need to see your code, otherwise we'll just be guessing (again).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
String original = "1,1,87 gandhi road,600005";
String[] s = original.split(",");
for (String t : s) {
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

Output:

> 1
>   1
>   87 gandhi road
>   600005

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] str = "1,1,87 gandhi road,600005".split(",");
        for (String s : str) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> 1
>   1
>  
>   87 gandhi road
>  
>   600005

Comment: Please mind, that I've changed your `print` call to a `println` call so your code produces the output you've given.