# Split command does not function with Scanner

Tags: java, split, java.util.scanner

I tried doing something like what these people have done:
[How to split a comma-separated string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631715/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-string)
But when I do the following:

```
String UserInput = new Scanner(System.in).next();
GradesNonInt = Arrays.asList(UserInput.replaceAll("\\s","").split(","));
System.out.println(GradesNonInt.size());
```

When I input a string like "1,2,3" I get 3 printed. When I type "1, 2, 3" I get 1 printed. For some reason, it does not want to work when the string has spaces in it.

As one of the answers below said, entering "1, 2, 3" directly seems to work fine, but yet when taken from the Scanner(System.in).next(), it is not.

Answer (score 2):

I tried following code and it printed 3 when I used "1, 2, 3" in UserInput string

```
    String UserInput = "1, 2, 3";
    List<String> GradesNonInt = Arrays.asList(UserInput.replaceAll("\\s","").split(","));
    System.out.println(GradesNonInt.size());
```

The issue is not with split but this is happening cause Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace and that's why this behaviour is shown. [Refer this link.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

If you want you can change the delimiter to something else than space by using [useDelimiter method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.util.regex.Pattern)) of Scanner class

---

> **UPDATE**

To change the delimiter to next line and to ensure the code accept spaces in the strings, you can change your code to following

```
    String UserInput = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\n").next();
    List<String> GradesNonInt = Arrays.asList(UserInput.replaceAll("\\s","").split(","));
    System.out.println(GradesNonInt.size());
```

Comment: Thank, I hadn't actually realized that the UserInput might be the problem. I will edit the OP.

Comment: Which leads to conclusion that problem lies in `new Scanner(System.in).next();`...

Comment: @JoelHemphill If this issue is solved, then you can accept the answer which helped you solved this query

Comment: `useDelimiter("\n")` is bad style. We already have `nextLine()` method for that. Also it can cause a lot of problems if we use this code on OS which is using only `\r`. It will also prevent us from such Scanner's `hasNextInt` method with data in form `1 2 3`.

Comment: @Pshemo I understand that part. Just wanted to show the use of delimiter. He can choose any other delimiter based on his needs or even the `nextLine()` method

Comment: Fair enough, but I will leave that comment to show potential problems with `\n` delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that `Scanner#next()` can return only next *token* (until it finds next delimiter, or end of data). So for input like `1, 2, 3,` it will return `1,`.

Use `Scanner#nextLine()` to read entire line.

Also ***don't create new instance of Scanner each time you want to read data from user***. Create one Scanner handling `System.in` per application and reuse it.