# How to pass different values in a StringBuilder as separate parameter with a Process call for executing python script from Java

Tags: java, python, process, stringbuilder, processbuilder

I am executing a `python script` from `Java` using `Process` approach. I have this code part where I have a `StringBuilder` with following structure:`(val1,val2,...)`.

Now I have this part of code which uses `Process` approach to execute the python scripts from within Java code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python","test1.py");
Process p = pb.start();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
int ret = new Integer(in.readLine()).intValue();
```

Now what I want is to first check if my `StringBuilder` `str` is empty or not i.e. the string is just `()` and there is nothing inside `()` in `str`. If it is not empty (i.e. there are values inside `()`) then I need to pass each value as a separate parameter with the `Process` call for my python script. For example if my `str` is `(val1,val2)` then I need to pass `val1` and `val2` as a separate parameters in the `Process` call for executing the python script from within Java code.

How can I modify my current code to include this?

Comment: Your string builder will not contain be `"()"` for the code given.

Comment: @AndyTurner Why will the StringBuilder not contain `"()"`?

Comment: Because it always has 10 integers and commas written to it.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a StringBuilder at all instead of just passing your arguments along?

```
new ProcessBuilder("python", "test1.py", "val1", "val2")
```

You can dynamically create that parameter array if necessary.

```
List<String> args = new ArrayList<>();
args.add("python");
args.add("test1.py");
args.addAll(myOtherArgsThatICollectedInAList);
new ProcessBuilder(args.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: Theres a long code before the code I have posted which is forming the `StringBuilder`. So using it is necessity.

Comment: One can always refactor. If not, you'll have to split your long string by comma (which might be error-prone).

Comment: The way I have shown the `StringBuilder` is emphasize on the structure of the StringBuilder getting formed. The actual code that is forming is not the one I have shown. Its more of a representation

Comment: can you show how to do it? My StringBuilder structure will always be `(val1,val2)` or just `()` if there is no `val` coming in.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631715/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-string?rq=1

Comment: based on the answer in the link it will produce a list of strings. How can I then pass each element of that list as a parameter in a Process call?

Comment: Just one more doubt. My StringBuilder has structure `(val1,val2...)`. So if I do split(",") it will split at `,` but theres extra `(` and `)` at the beginning and ending of the StringBuilder. How can I remove those so that `myOtherArgsThatICollectedInAList ` only has `val1`,`val2` and so on?

Comment: throw away the first and the last character ?