# Seperate ids or values in a string using comma as delimiter

Tags: java

I get a string of unit ids from this:

```
 String units = FolderUtil.getInstance().getUnits(folderId);
```

which looks like this:

```
[1886bec8-334b-4be0-bcb6-3594c7e454b6, 4818dda2-e124-460d-b910-dc0386ceb138, e95cdfcb-14d6-4065-a69d-8f0213e1f8b4]
```

How can I separate each id so I can pass each value individually into another method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a comma-separated string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631715/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working solution using `substring` instead of `replace`:

```java
String s1 = "[1886bec8-334b-4be0-bcb6-3594c7e454b6, 4818dda2-e124-460d-b910-dc0386ceb138, e95cdfcb-14d6-4065-a69d-8f0213e1f8b4]";
String s2 = s1.substring(1,s1.length()-1);
String[] ss = s2.split(",");
for (String str : ss) {
        System.out.println(str.trim());
}
```

Although by looking at that string, it looks like a string representation of an array of strings. Hence, if you developed the `getUnits` method, I'd advise you to refactor it to return the correct type and not the result of an `arrayOfUnits.toString()`.

Comment: Perfect! I couldn't get the for loop right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String units = FolderUtil.getInstance().getUnits(folderId);
String[] unitParts = units.replace("[","").replace("]", "").split(", ")
```