# Json - One key multiple values

Tags: java, android, json

I need to get one JSON value, but it is not working. I can already read the json data but I cannot add to the list and read just one or two values

```
 {
"item": [
    {
      "gallery": "user_files/goods/sOOsUcrM2Xorb3fbaD9bVoK9wDKDkmEjeKKZrJC7.jpeg, user_files/goods/Csc9XgxKUEkdI3jts7f2gV22hPqAKh5cJGYkvf7k.jpeg"

    }}

       JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("result");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length();i++)
        {
          JSONObject m = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String gallery = m.getString("gallery");
            urls.add(gallery);
        }
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),urls.get(0),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: split by `,`? that is a bad JSON though, should have been an array

Comment: Hi could you please edit your json to make it valid and fix your code formatting? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: either or json is incomplete or invalid. please verify you json format first. then try to ask to the point

Comment: Do you have control over the JSON or is it coming from somewhere outside your control?

Answer (score 1):

First of all its a bad JSON format to read on Android or on any platform because coma(`,`) can never separate the JSON data...
and still, if you want to use it then follow [How to split a comma-separated string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631715/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-string)

Answer (score -1):

As I Understand,you need one value only from multiple values.

you should try this.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("result");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length();i++)
        {
          JSONObject m = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String gallery = m.getString("gallery");
            String[] array=gallery.split(",");
            // array[0]; contains 1st value
            // array[1]; contains 2nd value
            urls.add(gallery);
        }
```