# Store String variable to String Array

Tags: java, arrays, string

this like a string array {hi, hi, hello}, but if I have a string that is shaped like that, can i do this by entering a string variable into the string array ?

like this: 
String animal = "kangaroo, rabbit, dog, cat, elephant"; 
String[] array = { animal };

the result is: 
array[0] : kangaroo 
array[1] : rabbit

Comment: Did you try to search the solution first before posting your question? A simple search would have given you hundreds of links with the required solution.

Comment: Another one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631715/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I declare and initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-do-i-declare-and-initialize-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

```
   String animal = "kangaroo, rabbit, dog, cat, elephant";
   String[] array = animal.split(", ");
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Comment: Use `\\s*,\\s*` instead of `", "` because there may or may not be space(s) after comma.