# How to remove all white spaces in java

Tags: java, string, whitespace

I have a programming assignment and part of it requires me to make code that reads a line from the user and removes all the white space within that line. 
the line can consist of one word or more.

What I was trying to do with this program is have it analyze each character until it finds a space and then save that substring as the first token. then loop again until it reaches no more tokens or the end of the line.

I keep on getting this when I try to compile it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index   out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:694)
    at trim.main(trim.java:23)
```

Here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner ;
import java.lang.Character;
import java.lang.String ;
public class trim
{
        public static void main (String[]args)
        {

        String a  ;
        String b  ;
        String c ;
        char aChar ;
        int i = 0 ;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        a = scan.nextLine();
        a =a.trim() ;


         for ( ; i >= 0 ; i++ )
         {
           aChar = a.charAt(i) ;
           if (aChar != 32)
           {
            a = a.substring(0,i+1);
           }
           else
           {
            b = a.substring(i,160) ;
            b= b.trim();
            c = c + a ;
            c = c.trim() ;
            a = b ;
            i = 0 ;
           }
           if (b.equals(null))
           {
            i = -1 ;
           }
         }
        }
}
```

easier ways to do this is appreciated, but I still want to get this program working.

and I can't use sentinels in the input.

---

Thanks everybody for all the help,

I will use the simpler method , and will read the javadoc.

Comment: the function in `substring` not `substr`

Comment: You need help from "Head first core java" book. Read it ASAP.

Comment: thanks, i guess the site that told me to use substr was wrong.

Comment: Have you considered reading the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)?

Comment: consider reading Java naming convention - http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm

Comment: Use `a.replaceAll("\\p{Blank}","")` It will remove all the spaces and the tabs from the String

Answer (score 236):

`java.lang.String` class has method `substring` not `substr` , thats the error in your program.

Moreover you can do this in one single line if you are ok in using regular expression.

```
a.replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

Comment: Is the `+` selector necessary in the regex when using replaceAll?

Comment: No its not necessary but if user enters more than one whitespace than this snippet will take care of such situations.

Comment: Even without the `+` multiple spaces will get removed, since they will all match individually and be removed as one by one.

Comment: `replaceAll("\\p{Blank}","")` can also be used as it removes all the spaces and tabs from the String

Answer (score 77):

Why not use a regex for this?

```
a = a.replaceAll("\\s","");
```

In the context of a regex, `\s` will remove anything that is a space character (including space, tab characters etc).  You need to escape the backslash in Java so the regex turns into `\\s`.  Also, **since Strings are immutable it is important that you assign the return value of the regex to** `a`.

Comment: i think `a.replaceAll("\\s+","")`will be a bit faster.

Comment: @roottraveller why it will be faster?

Comment: I think the  + indicates that one or more occurances.

Answer (score 66):

The most intuitive way of doing this without using `literals` or `regular expressions`:

```
yourString.replaceAll(" ","");
```

Comment: You're right. Makes sense. Why do you think "\\s" is more preferable?

Comment: they are identical. `" "` is more intuitive, since novices can be not aware of literal `\s`

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ are they? Wouldn't `" "` match only space and not all whitespace?

Comment: @Enerccio, exactly! But `replaceAll` means it will apply to all characters in the sting.

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ but asker asked for whitespace, is `" "` is incorrect, it should be  `\s` no?

Comment: Downvoted because this is answer is wrong; it shows how to remove a space but not all whitespaces.

ISO/IEC/IEEE 24765:2010, term 3.3322 defines a whitespace as:
"1. the nondisplaying formatting characters that are embedded within a block of free text. IEEE Std 1320.21998 (R2004) IEEE Standard for Conceptual Modeling Language Syntax and Semantics for IDEF1X97 (IDEFobject).3.1.210"

Answer (score 25):

Replace all the spaces in the String with empty character.

```
String lineWithoutSpaces = line.replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
String str = "Your string with     spaces";
str = str.replace(" " , "");
```

Comment: I guess this won't work with tabs.

Comment: answer with tab is coverd here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455794/removing-whitespace-from-strings-in-java

Comment: Downvoted because this is answer is wrong; it shows how to remove a space but not all whitespaces.

ISO/IEC/IEEE 24765:2010, term 3.3322 defines a whitespace as:
"1. the nondisplaying formatting characters that are embedded within a block of free text. IEEE Std 1320.21998 (R2004) IEEE Standard for Conceptual Modeling Language Syntax and Semantics for IDEF1X97 (IDEFobject).3.1.210"

Answer (score 15):

Try:

```
  string output = YourString.replaceAll("\\s","")
```

*s - indicates space character (tab characters etc)*

Answer (score 10):

```
public static String removeSpace(String s) {
    String withoutspaces = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) != ' ')
            withoutspaces += s.charAt(i);

    }
    return withoutspaces;

}
```

This is the easiest and most straight forward method to remove spaces from a String.

Answer (score 7):

```
package com.infy.test;

import java.util.Scanner ;
import java.lang.String ;

public class Test1 {


    public static void main (String[]args)
    {

        String a  =null;


        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("*********White Space Remover Program************\n");
        System.out.println("Enter your string\n");
    a = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input String is  :\n"+a);


        String b= a.replaceAll("\\s+","");

        System.out.println("\nOutput String is  :\n"+b);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Cant you just use String.replace(" ", "");

Comment: Exactly... isn't that the easiest way?

Comment: Downvoted because this is answer is wrong; it shows how to remove a space but not all whitespaces.

ISO/IEC/IEEE 24765:2010, term 3.3322 defines a whitespace as:
"1. the nondisplaying formatting characters that are embedded within a block of free text. IEEE Std 1320.21998 (R2004) IEEE Standard for Conceptual Modeling Language Syntax and Semantics for IDEF1X97 (IDEFobject).3.1.210"

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression to delete white spaces , try that snippet:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(scan.nextLine().replaceAll(" ", ""));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String a="string with                multi spaces ";
//or this 
String b= a.replaceAll("\\s+"," ");

String c= a.replace("    "," ").replace("   "," ").replace("  "," ").replace("   "," ").replace("  "," ");
```

//it work fine with any spaces

*don't forget space in sting b

Comment: Use the [edit] link to edit your answers instead of posting new ones.

Answer (score 2):

```
trim.java:30: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method substr(int,int)
location: class java.lang.String
b = a.substr(i,160) ;
```

There is no method like `substr` in String class.

use String.substring() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean flag = true;
while(flag) {
    s = s.replaceAll(" ", "");
    if (!s.contains(" "))
        flag = false;
}
return s;
```

Answer (score -10):

```
String a="string with                multi spaces ";

String b= a.replace("    "," ").replace("   "," ").replace("  "," ").replace("   "," ").replace("  "," ");
```

//it work fine with any spaces

Comment: This does not remove all white space.  It does not work on large strings of spaces.  It does not take advantage of the built-in methods for handling spaces.  Most of all, it does not solve the problem with the user's code.  This is homework: removing the student's original solution does not serve the correct instructional purpose, unless that solution is fatally flawed.