# How to take scanner input without space

Tags: java, parsing

I have a homework question that wants me to write a

> Program that takes three names and their scores from a user by using delimiters. Example:
>
> ```
> Tom:54, Matt:12, Ali:89
> ```

I keep getting an input mismatch exception when Java is assigning `user2Score`. I am currently testing my program but scanner seems to take in `user2` as `" Matt"` instead of `"Matt"`. I'm not sure if my delimiter syntax is correct. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class General {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("[: | ,*\\s]");

        String user1;
        String user2;
        String user3;

        int user1Score;
        int user2Score;
        int user3Score;

        System.out.println("Please enter the user name and their score:");
        user1 = input.next();
        user1Score = input.nextInt();
        user2 = input.next();
        user2Score = input.nextInt();
        user3 = input.next();
        user3Score = input.nextInt();


        System.out.println(user1 + " " + user1Score + "\n" + user2 + " " + user2Score);
    }

}
```

Comment: why do you need "," and  "<space>" to separate the input pairs?

Comment: The teacher wants the program to accept it as if he's typing Tom:54, Matt:12, Ali:89

Answer (score 2):

you can use the trim()-method of String. This elimates all spaces at the beginning and at the end of the string.

Comment: If your input variable is taking one string like "Tom:54, Matt:12, Ali:89", then trim() wouldn't work because it only removes white space at the beginning and end of the string.  Instead, replaceAll("\\s+","") might work per this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633228/how-to-remove-all-white-spaces-in-java

Comment: I tried adding the .trim() to user2 = input.next() but it still did not work?

Comment: I also tried changing user2 = input.next().replaceAll("\\s+",""); but It didn't seem to work