# separating string into separate variables without arrays

Tags: java, string

I need help separating a string into separate variables. I am trying to make a program that will get user input using nextLine() then i would need to separate the characters in that string.

For example the user could input the line 23plus or 2 3 plus.

Ive read about .split but that would only work when there are spaces in the input. I could put say that the first number is charAt(0) but how would i get the rest?

Comment: How can your program distinguish between `23plus` meaning `23 plus` and `23plus` meaning `2 3 plus`?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Given the input `1234plus` what does your logic do? `12 34 plus` `1 234 plus`?

Comment: You cannot split a line unless you know the general structure of the line and how you're going to split it. You need to tell us these things as well as more examples of possible input and output if we're to help. As written your question doesn't make sense, and isn't answerable.

Comment: its supposed to be a single digit calculator. i would take one digit and do the operation

Comment: *"Ive read about .split but that would only work when there are spaces in the input"* That's not even *remotely* true: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String) You might also look at [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), or even just [`String#indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) and [`String#substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)).

Comment: You could probably just collect the line as a string, remove all of the whitespace and iteratively process each string element in a loop.

Comment: what would you use to get rid of the whitespaces?

Answer (score 1):

You say, the problem is 'one digit calculator' with postfixed notation 23+ :

- `digits = digits.replaceAll( "\\\\s","" );`
- First digit: `int op1 = Integer.parseInt( digits.charAt(0));`
- Second digit: `int op2 = Integer.parseInt( digits.charAt(1));`
- operator : `digits.charAt(2)`, as I suggest to use +, -, /, *, used in a switch/case
- result: 5

Comment: "user could input the line 23plus or 2 3 plus" - this doesn't deal with the second case very well...

Comment: how would this work if there are spaces so at index 1 there would be a space?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455794/removing-whitespace-from-strings-in-java

Comment: Purge the spaces with `s.replaceAll("\\s","");`

Comment: @Aubin if you add that to your answer I will remove the down vote as your answer will then answer the question fully.

Answer (score 0):

How about looping over the `String` char by char and checking if it's a digit:

```
    final List<Integer> values = new LinkedList<>();
    final StringBuilder operator = new StringBuilder();
    for (final char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            values.add(Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(c)));
        } else if (!Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
            operator.append(c);
        }
    }
```

**Note:** This will only work if the input is of the form "WdigitWdigitWoperator" where "W" is optional white space.

But I understand that that is the case from your question.

Another option is to use regex, this would look something like:

```
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\s*+(?<firstDigit>\\d)\\s*+(?<secondDigit>\\d)\\s*+(?<operator>\\w++)$");

    final Matcher matcher = p.matcher(input);
    if(matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group("firstDigit"));
        System.out.println(matcher.group("secondDigit"));
        System.out.println(matcher.group("operator"));
    }
```

If this is a homework assignment (which I suspect it is) this may not be an acceptable solution however.