# In java when converting a char array with spaces to a String how to remove the spaces in that String?

Tags: java

```
String output = new String(encryptText);
output = output.replaceAll("\\s", "");
return output;
```

`replaceAll("\\s", "");` doesn't work

Comment: your code seems to be fine. it should work. I would check what encryptText looks like

Comment: could you please share the input string? because str.replaceAll("\\s", ""); should work. You can also try str.replaceAll(" ", "");

Comment: You should add the error you get or an example of why the solution you posted doesn't work or your question seems to be a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455794/removing-whitespace-from-strings-in-java

Answer (score 2):

```
String output = new String(encryptText);
output = output.replaceAll(" ", "");
return output;
```

Comment: We have to say that this solution works only for "pure" whitespace characters. It doesn't catch "special" whitespace characters like tab (\t). Instead, the solution based on java.util.regex.Pattern: replaceAll("\\s", "") does work for every whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem then I searched a lot and found that, it is not a space character but a null value which is transformed into string from character array. This resolved the issue for me -

```
output.replaceAll(String.valueOf((char) 0), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me, see [here](http://ideone.com/mNTPN3)

Anyway you can use the [StringUtils.trimAllWhitespace](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#trimAllWhitespace%28java.lang.String%29) from the [spring framework](http://www.springsource.org/spring-community-download):

```
output = StringUtils.trimAllWhitespace(output);
```

Comment: as I understand this function not from JDK. it come with spring?

Comment: it saysThe method trimAllWhitespace(String) is undefined for the type

Comment: java.lang does not contain a class called StringUtils. Several third-party libs do, such as Apache Commons Lang or the Spring framework. 
In order to use it you need the relevant jar in your project classpath and import the correct class.

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak yes your right, http://www.springsource.org/spring-community-download

Comment: Sorry gues, i have forget to mention its part of the spring framework. i updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use the non-regex-version replace to do the job:

```
output = output.replace(" ", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.replaceAll(" ","")` or if you want to do it yourself without a lib call, use this.

```
        String encryptedString = "The quick brown fox ";
        char[] charArray = encryptedString.toCharArray();
        char [] copy = new char[charArray.length];
        int counter = 0;
        for (char c : charArray)
        {
            if(c != ' ')
            {
                copy[counter] = c;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        char[] result = Arrays.copyOf(copy, counter);
        System.out.println(new String(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
z = z.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

easiest and the simplest way for removing white spaces from the char [];