# removing white spaces from string value

Tags: java

i have a link `http://localhost:8080/reporting/pvsUsageAction.do?form_action=inline_audit_view&days=7&projectStatus=scheduled&justificationId=5&justificationName=        No Technicians in Area` in my struts based web application.

The variable in URL `justificationName` have some spaces before its vales as shown. when i get value of `justificationName`  using `request.getParameter("justificationName")` it gives me that value with spaces as given in the URL. i want to remove those spaces. i tried `trim()` i tries `str = str.replace(" ", "");` but any of them did not removed those spaces. can any one tell some other way to remove the space.

Noted one more thing that i did right click on the link and opened the link into new tab there i noticed that link looks like.

```
http://localhost:8080/reporting/pvsUsageAction.do?form_action=inline_audit_view&days=7&projectStatus=scheduled&justificationId=5&justificationName=%A0%A0%A0%A0%A0%A0%A0%A0No%20Technicians%20in%20Area
```

Notable point is that in the address bar it shows `%A0` for white spaces and also show `%20` for space as well see the link and tell the difference please if any one have idea about it.

**EDIT**
Here is my code

```
String justificationCode = "";
        if (request.getParameter("justificationName") != null) {            
            justificationCode = request.getParameter("justificationName");
        }
        justificationCode = justificationCode.replace(" ", "");
```

Note: replace function remove the space from inside the string but not removing starting spaces. 
e-g if my string is "    This is string" after using replace it becomes "    Thisisstring"

Thanks in advance

Comment: how did you use `str.replace()` ?

Comment: `str.replace(" ", "");` here it is

Comment: Did you use the *return value* of those methods? If you don't, then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: you have to assign the result of the operation to another variable. See the Javadoc for the `replace()` method. It returns another `String`.

Comment: Did you assign the return value of `str.replace()` to the original variable? Like `str = str.replace(" ", "");`

Comment: yes i used the returned value

Comment: Show your code where you remove space and refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455794/removing-whitespace-from-strings-in-java

Comment: Added the code please check now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Manual trim**

You need to remove the spaces the string. This will remove any number of consecutive spaces.

```
String trimmed = str.replaceAll(" +", "");
```

If you want to replace all whitespace characters:

```
String trimmed = str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

**URL Encoding**

You could also use an URLEncoder, which sounds like a more appropriate way to go:

```
import java.net.UrlEncoder;
String url = "http://localhost:8080/reporting/" + URLEncoder.encode("pvsUsageAction.do?form_action=inline_audit_view&days=7&projectStatus=scheduled&justificationId=5&justificationName= No Technicians in Area", "ISO-8859-1");
```

Answer (score 5):

Strings are immutable in Java, so the method doesn't change the string you pass but returns a new one. You must use the returned value :

```
str = str.replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: Well. It should. This really removes all standard white space. Your problem might be elsewhere, you should debug step by step to see what happens (or print the string before and after replacement).

Comment: trim only remove the spaces from the extremities. You'd use it as str = str.trim();

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the result of the `replace(String regex, String replacement)` operation to another variable. See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for the `replace(String regex, String replacement)` method. It returns a brand new `String` object and this is because the String(s) in Java are immutable. In your case, you can simply do the following

```
String noSpacesString = str.replace("\\s+", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceAll("\\s","")` It will remove all white space.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove the trailing and ending white spaces, then

[`s = s.trim();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)

Or if you want to remove all the spaces the use :

[s = s.replace(" ","");](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing  one is regular expression based or your own way of implementing the logic

```
replaceAll("\\s","")
```

or

```
    if (text.contains(" ") || text.contains("\t") || text.contains("\r") 
       || text.contains("\n"))   
    {  
   //code goes here
    }
```