# how to remove unicode spaces from String returned by reader.readLine()

Tags: java, android

I when i use reader.readLine(), the string length is always 80 chars and after the main string unicode spaces are padded up. 
Is there a way to remove those unwanted characters.
(java.io.RandomAccessFile reader)
String.trim is not working on this

Comment: The question is a bit too narrow. For example, I searched stackoverflow for "[java] internationalization trim" and "[java] unicode trim" and did *not* find this question. You really want a trim() function that is I18N/Unicode aware; if the question was phrased that way, more people would be able to find the answer below.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [StringUtils.strip](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#strip%28java.lang.String%29) from Commons Lang. It is Unicode-aware.

Comment: well it uses Character.isWhitespace which doesn't work well. It should use newer Character.isSpaceChar to be fully unicode-aware

Answer (score 3):

You can write a custom method in Java to remove the Unicode space characters , using  [Character.isWhitespace(char)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29) and [Character.isSpaceChar(char)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSpaceChar%28char%29) methods, for your specific purpose.

The Spring framework has a [StringUtils](http://static.springsource.org/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html) class with a [trimWhitespace(String)](http://static.springsource.org/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#trimWhitespace%28java.lang.String%29) method which appears to be based on `Character.isWhitespace(char)` from the [source code here](http://git.springsource.org/spring-mobile/spring-android/blobs/063e6216bd746786532515cdc2f7f1d670e98fd0/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.java).

Answer (score 0):

use Google Guava

```
CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.trimFrom(source);
```

or try this https://gist.github.com/michalbcz/4861a2b8ed73bb73764e909b87664cb2

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want a big libs. Just use:

`str.replaceAll("^[\\s\\p{Z}]+|[\\s\\p{Z}]+$", "");`

Testing

```
    public static String trim(String str) {
        return str.replaceAll("^[\\s\\p{Z}]+|[\\s\\p{Z}]+$", "");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(trim("\t tes ting \u00a0").length());
        System.out.println(trim("\t testing \u00a0").length());
        System.out.println(trim("tes ting \u00a0").length());
        System.out.println(trim("\t tes ting").length());
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

would have been faster to just search stackoverflow for this question becoz there are multiple questions on that topic there. well, try this:

```
st.replaceAll("\\s","")
```

check this one here:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455794/removing-whitespace-from-strings-in-java)

Comment: That removes ALL space, though, not just the padding.