# What must my code look like in order to remove white space in a String in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

What must my code look like in order to remove white space in a String in Java?

I have tried the following:

```
/* Option 1 */ String x=splitString.replaceAll("\\s+","");
/* Option 2 */ String x=splitString.trim()
```

Neither of these give me the result I expect.

Comment: explain doesn't work, because the first one would certainly replace all the whitespaces.

Comment: You want to remove all the white space or only left and right side trimming?

Comment: just to make it clear: x has no whitespace after method call. splitString stays the same as Strings are immutable in java

Comment: try splitString.replace(' ','');

Comment: Indeed, a poorly asked question on a subject that a lot of people understand seems to generate a lot of activity!

Comment: Only left side remove white space

Comment: Yeah explain wat not works ..

Comment: Did you mean to do - `splitString = splitString.replaceAll("\\s+","");`?

Comment: st.replaceAll("\\s+","")--> this i'm sure that works i use it...maybe the reason is that is telling @Marco

Comment: Ya I know but its also doesn't work

Comment: It sounds to me like you've got a potentially non-breaking whitespace character, which won't be removed by trim() or matched by \s. Try printing out the int value of the space to verify this.

Comment: `@Panchotiya Vipul` write your string on which you want to remove whitespace..

Comment: At least post the string, so that there will be a clear idea of why replaceAll is not working.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The small army of people thinking that `\s` matches **all** whitespace are quite simply wrong! [Looking in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) we can see that it matches `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]` - a bunch of **breaking** whitespace (or in other words, just plain old ordinary whitespace.)

Likewise, `trim()` doesn't match all whitespace either (this is worse, it matches all characters that have a value <= space, most of which *aren't* technically whitespace) - so giving an example with spaces before and after a string, then calling `trim()` on it, is not a comprehensive test by any stretch of the imagination.

Given the above, the (regex based) code you've provided will definitely strip all breaking whitespace from the string, so it sounds to me like you have a potentially **non-breaking** whitespace character in there. This is especially likely to be the case if you've pulled whatever text it is from some external source rather than just writing the string in code (a portion of a HTML page for example may be the most likely candidate.)

If this is the case, then try :

```
String x=splitString.replaceAll("\\p{Z}","");
```

...where `\p{Z}` is a shortcut for matching *any* kind of whitespace, not just non breaking spaces. `\p{Separator}` is its longer (equivalent) form.

Comment: +1 note: trim() removes trailing/leading characters <= space.  This includes many non space characters, and misses many higher whitespace characters.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks for that - I didn't know that at all! Have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @berry120 It is a Java 1.0 function which had a very simple view of what you might want to trim from a String ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I guessed that from its behaviour - reeks of a leftover mechanism from old times that's now unfortunately baked in!

Comment: I've tried the `"\\p{Z}"` pattern, but get a "PatternSyntaxException" in Java 7. However, `"[ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]"` (must escape backslashes in Regex) works.

Comment: @AgiHammerthief Only got Java 8 in front of me at the mo, but it certainly works fine there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code will help you!

```
String st = " Hello I am White Space   ";
System.out.println(st);  // Print Original String
   //st = st.replaceAll("\\s+",""); // Remove all white space and assign to same
   st = st.trim(); // It is working fine.
System.out.println(st);  // Print after removing all white space.
```

Comment: First see the question i already put in the question

Comment: at my end it is working fine. it is removing the white space.

Comment: -1, This code is exactly equivalent to the code in the question!