# Facebook API exception "This link could not be posted."

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using `facebook sdk 3.6` for `android`. I am trying to share link to users fb wall through my app. 
I have used

```
Bundle postParam = new Bundle();
postParam.putString("link","http://mylink.com/image/09324 324.jpg"
postParam.putString("caption","my caption");
… … …

Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParam, HttpMethod.POST, reqCallback);
            RequestAsyncTask reqTask = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            reqTask.execute();
```

The link contains space  character.
I can visit that link from browser simply by replacing the space character by `%20`. But when i do the same using `link.replaceAll(" ","%20");`, i get `Facebook api exception`,

```
ErrorMessage = This link could not be posted.
ErrorCode = 1500
ErrorType=  FacebookApiException
```

I supposed this as url encoding problem, but it is neither get solved using `URLEncoder` nor by replacing space by `%20` by `replaceAll` method of `String` object.
There are no any non-printable characters in the string. 
**Note:** The same link when copied from `log cat` output and added back to that `bundle` works fine.
**Update:** When i retried to post the same link (not `log cat` copied) from program, it get successfully posted.


What is the problem and how could it be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Facebook will block a link or domain from their blacklist. One way to test this is if you try to post directly onto Facebook with the same link.

Link below might be of help, they suggest you use https://safeweb.norton.com to if the link is safe or not and therefore blacklisted.

https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=541062392623556

Answer (score 0):

hmmm maybe using

```
link.replaceAll("\\s","");
```

\s = Anything that is a space character (including space, tab characters etc)

as you can see here:

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455794/removing-whitespace-from-strings-in-java)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: No, that is not working either. still The same link when copied from log cat output and added back to that bundle works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i have used facebook shareDialog and present user with the status dialog box where app can populate the `link`, `picture,`description`and`message`(message is only populated on webview i.e. in device with no fb application installed) property and the user can edit/fill in the status and post on his on timeline.

This is more nicer way to post on somebody's wall because the user can see what he is posting.

*Sorry to answer my own question so lately, though i have solved it already.*