# how many letter occur in a text?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, java.util.scanner

I got it working but it is also counting the spaces between the words that are being typed.
All i care is for the letters to be count and not the spaces. 
How or what can i do to change this? where am i messing up or missed something

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LetterCount
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{

    System.out.println("Type something ");
    Scanner n = new Scanner (System.in);
    String s = "";
    s = n.nextLine();
    char []c = s.toCharArray();
    int sz = c.length;
    int i =0, j=0, counter=0;

    for (i=0; i<sz; i++){
        counter =0;

            for(j=0; j<sz; j++)
            {

                if (j< i&& c[i] == c[j])
                {
                    break;
                }   

                if (c[j] == c[i])
                {
                    counter++;
                }

                if (j==sz-1)
                {
                    System.out.println("the character "+c[i]+" is present "+counter+" times");
                }
            }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Please try something and show us, before asking.

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;

public class LetterCount
{
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
  
  System.out.println("Type something ");
  Scanner n = new Scanner (System.in);
  String s = "";
  s = n.nextLane(); // is telling cannot find symbol
  char []c = s.toCharArray();
  int sz = c.length;
  int i =0, j=0, counter=0;
  
  for (i=0; i<sz; i++){
   counter =0;
    
    for(j=0; j<sz; j++)
    {
     
     if (j< i&& c[i] == c[j])

Answer (score 0):

What you'd want to do is remove the whitespace from the string before you count the letters;

[Removing whitespace from strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455794/removing-whitespace-from-strings-in-java)