# how to remove blank space from the below String

Tags: json, string

When I am fetching the response from web service in a string buffer and converting it to string, it is providing me the below string.

There are plenty of blank spaces from the given String which needs to be removed:

```
{                               'GetPolicyResp' : {                         'VersionID': '1.0'                      ,'TransactionID': 'urn:uuid:ea2051c5-c1b1-44cd-bcae-a4a06079e2bd'                        ,'Status' : {                      'StatusCode': '0'                       ,'Detail': 'Success'                             }                      ,'Path': '1'                        ,'RequestReceivedDate': '2015-04-23'                        , 'healthPolicy':{                                'classifications': 'AWH'                        ,'primaryPolicyType': 'Medical'                                          }                           ,'primaryNetworkCategory':{                                            'code': 'ACOCTXM4'                          ,'description': 'Aetna Whole Health - Memorial Hermann Accountable Care Network'                                               }                                                                              }               }"
```

I need to remove the blank space from the above string to get a perfect json response.

P.S. I have tried `trim` and `replaceAll` but was of no help.

Comment: First off, what language are you coding in?

Comment: Without any code or knowing what language your using I am going to go with using the backspace key? ;)

Comment: Use Java `st.replaceAll("\\s","")` method.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455794/removing-whitespace-from-strings-in-java

Comment: Yeah - based on python - simply use: `st.replace(" ", "")`.

Comment: @TiyebBellal and Manoj Awasthi : This will replace also the spaces inside the values.

Comment: Your code isn't just problematic because of spaced - it contains invalid JSON regardless.