# Unable to remove white space in String

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to remove white space in a String, adressString (see below).

[image]

To do so, I'm using the folowing piece of code :

`adressString.replaceAll("\r","");`

However, this does not work : I'm stil having this whitespace (see below) :

[image]

Solution :

I needed to declare another String :

`String adressWithoutCarriageReturn = adressString.replaceAll("\r", "");`

Comment: Check this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455794/removing-whitespace-from-strings-in-java

Comment: I just tested it , this does not work too :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one more slash like below:

```
adressString.replaceAll("\\r","");
```

As "\" is a special character.

Comment: You should explain why!

Comment: Because "\" is a special character.

Comment: @Jens there is nothing need to explain, as its special character.

Comment: @Riser.Add this comment to the answer and you have explained it.

Comment: for some other people like you.

Comment: I also tried this solution, this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Y can't we use it like below.

```
String a =  str.replace(" ","");
```

Comment: I tried, this does not work.

Comment: can you give me your string?.. i ll test it

Comment: @wholegrain ... where the spaces in your string "5.135.222.75\r"