# How to ignore spaces between text editview Android

Tags: android, string-formatting, editview

I am trying to ignore spaces in editview between text, I am not quite sure how I can go about doing this. I know I can use trim feature to ignore spaces before and after the full text but how do I ignore space between strings if there is any;

```
String myTextEdited myText.getText().toString().trim();
```

For example, if I have / user types in this;

```
Allan Bob
3523 JKO
NY1 U90
```

I want to ingore spaces when I read this in my if statement or put it in another variable for example;

String name = "AllanBob"

For example, to ignore upper and lower cases I am doing this;

```
 if (myText.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(userInput)) {
                    // do something
                } else {
                    // do something
                }
```

What I would like to do is add another feature in here that also ignores spaces before, between and after text e.g. instead of;

```
   myname   is Henry      .   (space until here)
```

It should read it as mynameishenry but to the user it still appears as they have written it.

Please let me know if my question was not clear, I will try explaining it better

EDITED:

is it possible to ignore spaces in string that I have inside my if statement. For example;

```
if (myText.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Henry 0887")) {
                    // do something
                } else {
                    // do something
                }
```

but currently if the user types in henry0887, the if statement does not validate it because I added a space inside my validation text and therefoe its looking for a space in the text, is it possible to over come this, so even if I have space inside my validation it ignores it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455794/removing-whitespace-from-strings-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
String  myString = myEditText.getText().toString();
myString  = myString .replace(" ", "");
```

Hope it helps

EDIT:

```
if (myText.getText().toString().replace(" ", "").equalsIgnoreCase(userInput) || myText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(userInput)) {...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt reply. How can I put this in if statement?

Comment: @Henry, like this: `if (myText.getText().toString().replace(" ", "").equalsIgnoreCase(userInput)) {...`

Answer (score 1):

use `replaceAll()` method.
`str = str.replace(" ","");`
or for all space chars:
`str = str.replace("\\s+","");`

**EDIT**

```
if (myText.getText().toString().replace("\\s+","").equalsIgnoreCase(userInput)) {
                    // do something
                } else {
                    // do something
                }
```

**EDIT2**

```
if (myText.getText().toString().replace("\\s+","").equalsIgnoreCase("Henry 0887".replace("\\s+",""))) {
                    // do something
                } else {
                    // do something
                }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt reply. How can I put this in if statement?

Comment: Please see edit on my post, would you  be able to help with that please.

Comment: Thanks, short and concise :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

if(myText.getText().toString().trim().replace(" ","").equalsIgnoreCase(userInput)) {
                    // do something
                } else {
                    // do something
                }

Hope this helps.