# How to convert a body of text to a single line string in Java?

Tags: java, string

I would like to convert a body of text which is in a form similar to this:

```
text here
text there
text everywhere
```

into a single string which would look like the following:

```
textheretexttheretexteverywhere
```

EDIT: The text on multiple lines is to be copied from one file and pasted into the input of the program, however it isn't necessarily a .txt file.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public static void converter(String inputString){

    String refinedString = inputString.replaceAll("\\s+","").replaceAll("\\\\n+", "");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Refined string: " + refinedString);
}
```

Here is my main function where I am calling my `converter` method:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println("Enter string: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String originalString = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Original string: " + originalString);
        converter(originalString);
    }
```

Many thanks in advance!

(I'm new to programming so sorry if I'm missing something really obvious, I've tried everything I could find on Stack overflow)

Comment: What's going wrong with this solution?

Comment: Just realized, your `"\\s+"` replacement should suffice actually.

Comment: Is there an issue with the code you wrote? There's no need for the second replace AFAIK, but the first replace should take care of all whitespaces. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455794/removing-whitespace-from-strings-in-java

Comment: "sorry if I'm missing something really obvious".. Yes, the obvious thing you are missing is that you have already solved your problem. :)

Comment: When I copy and paste a body of text as the input, the program only follows this process for the first line and then terminates. I tried using a loop but I must be doing it wrong

Comment: Please post the code where you call your `converter` method since it sounds like the problem you're describing is related to your input.

Comment: 'public static void main(String [] args){
  
  System.out.println("Enter string: ");
  
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String originalString = input.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Original string: " + originalString);
        
        converter(originalString);
  
 }'

Comment: (Sorry I don't know how to format the code for comments)

Comment: add the back-ticks around the code. these: `

Comment: ` public static void main(String [] args){ System.out.println("Enter string: "); Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); String originalString = input.nextLine(); System.out.println(); System.out.println("Original string: " + originalString); converter(originalString); } `

Comment: Edit your question and post the code in there - makes it much easier for everyone to see!

Comment: Alright, thanks for the advice, will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much got it! The only thing you are "missing" is that you added the extra `.replaceAll` when you didn't need to.

Also, it sounds like you may have different types of input, but here is a solution based on your code:

**EDIT**: Here is the solution below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println("Enter string: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<> ();
        String line = null;
        while (!(line = input.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
        StringBuilder myOriginalString = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : lines) {
            myOriginalString.append(s);
            myOriginalString.append(" ");
            myOriginalString.append("\n");
        }
        String originalString = myOriginalString.toString();
        System.out.println("Original string: \n"  + originalString);
        converter(originalString);
    }

    public static void converter(String inputString){
        String refinedString = inputString.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Refined string: " + refinedString);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Enter string: 
text here
text there
text everywhere

Original string: 
text here 
text there 
text everywhere 


Refined string: textheretexttheretexteverywhere

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I did my best to model it around the type of input you would be giving. Based on your question, I assume you would be copying and pasting text to the prompt when you run your program. If you are looking to read from a file, then Mahbubur Rahman's answer is correct (and I won't replicate it in this answer as he deserves the credit.)

Comment: Thank you, there's just one problem: I can't enter the string with many linebreaks (\n) because the purpose of the program is to copy a body of text straight into the input and have it converted. I'll try post my main function and show you what I mean

Comment: `public class Example {
 
 public static void main(String [] args){
  
  System.out.println("Enter string: ");
  
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String originalString = input.nextLine();
 
        System.out.println("Original string: " + originalString);
        
        converter(originalString);
 }
 
 public static void converter(String inputString){
  
  String refinedString = inputString.replaceAll("\\s+","").replaceAll("\\\\n+", "");
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Refined string: " + refinedString);
 }`

Comment: @MatijaMilenovic thanks for the additional info. Edited your question for you and added in the updated solution above. It should work for you.

Comment: You're welcome @MatijaMilenovic! Good luck and welcome to programming and StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
String line = "";
File f = new File("Path to your file");
FileReader reader = new FileReader(f)
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
String str = "";
while((line = br.readlLine())!=null)
{
    str += line; 
}

System.out.println(str);
```

for spaces:

```
str = StringUtils.replace(str," ","");
```

Comment: u forgot the spaces.

Comment: StringUtils is from apache commons library.

Comment: @shank : Thanks for the reminder. Was about to sleep coz of late night here  and mistaken for hurry.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
String list = "text here\n";
list += "text there\n";
list += "text everywhere\n";

System.out.println("Original :\n"+list);

list= list.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "");
System.out.println("New :\n"+list);
```