# Remove whitespaces in string with Scala

Tags: scala

I want to remove the whitespaces in a string.

```
Input: "le ngoc ky quang"  
Output: "lengockyquang"
```

I tried the `replace` and `replaceAll` methods but that did't work.

Comment: String in scala is java.lang.String, already has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455794/removing-whitespace-from-strings-in-java

Comment: What's the version of scala that you're using?

Comment: i use Scala IDE ver 4.2.x plugin with Eclipse

Comment: Define "didn't work"

Answer (score 34):

Try the following:

```
input.replaceAll("\\s", "")
```

Answer (score 26):

You can filter out all whitespace characters.

```
"With spaces".filterNot(_.isWhitespace)
```

Comment: Probably the most correct answer. `isWhitespace` will also check for tabs and break lines.

Answer (score 7):

Consider splitting the string by any number of whitespace characters (`\\s+`) and then re-concatenating the split array,

```
str.split("\\s+").mkString
```

Comment: Nice that this takes out `\n` characters as well - if that is a use case one has.

Answer (score 5):

```
val str = "le ngoc ky quang"
str.replace(" ", "")

//////////////////////////////////////
scala> val str = "le ngoc ky quang"
str: String = le ngoc ky quang

scala> str.replace(" ", "")
res0: String = lengockyquang

scala>
```

Answer (score 4):

According to [alvinalexander](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-convert-multiple-spaces-to-single-space-regex) it shows there how to replace more than white spaces to one space. The same logic you can apply, but instead of one space you should replace to empty string.

```
input.replaceAll(" +", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the trim method. Is very easy. visit this guide [https://www.includehelp.com/scala/string-trim-method.aspx#:~:text=The%20trim()%20method%20defined,characters%20using%20the%20trim%20method](https://www.includehelp.com/scala/string-trim-method.aspx#:%7E:text=The%20trim()%20method%20defined,characters%20using%20the%20trim%20method).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).