# Java: Hash Function Inputted Strings

Tags: java, string, hash, hashcode

I am seeking help creating a hash function that will take user data inputted from a string and convert it into an integer value, all the while skipping white spaces. I am stumped on why it's not working, and how to get it to get white spaces that may be entered and would appreciate the help.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inScan;
    String inStr;
    int outHash;

    inScan = new Scanner(System.in); // Assignment of Scanner

    System.out.print("Enter string to create hash: "); // Asks for String Input
    inStr = inScan.nextLine(); // String Input

    // Start of Hash Function
    String hashValue = inStr;
    hashValue = inStr.hashCode();
    System.out.println(hashValue);
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: What isn't working?  What output are your expecting and what are you getting?  What is the exact error message you see?

Comment: I'm expecting an integer output of some sort depending on whatever the string input is.

Comment: I believe there is an issue setting up the code to hash out the string.

Comment: If you are expecting an integer, why is `hashValue` of type `String`?

Comment: It should be `int hashValue`. Listen to what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: Changing String hashValue to int hashValue states there's a conversion error.

Comment: @Aramza You should not need the guess what is wrong here, the error message from your compiler tells you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Remove the unnecessary assignment here `String hashValue = inStr;` and instead just do `int hashValue = inStr.hashCode()`

Comment: That still appears to be a conversion, I don't see why it wouldn't work the other way.

Answer (score 1):

Your code calls `hashCode()` on unchanged `inStr`. You should clear out whitespace from `inStr` before calling `hashCode` to make sure hash codes of strings that differ only in white space are identical:

```
String a = "a bc";
String b = "ab c";
String c = "a b c";
int hashA = a.<remove-white-space>.hashCode();
int hashB = b.<remove-white-space>.hashCode();
int hashC = c.<remove-white-space>.hashCode();
```

`<remove-white-space>` is something you need to write. Consult [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5455794/335858) for help on this task.

If you do your task correctly, `hashA`, `hashB`, and `hashC` would be equal to each other.