# Replacing whitespaces on a String and breaking them using toCharArray() doesn't seem to work

Tags: java

I tried to do some String manipulation to play around with the methods available and I noticed that when I used the `replaceAll("\\s+","")` method to remove whitespaces in a String, it failed to do it.

```
System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
String word = scanner.next();
String cleansed = word.replaceAll("\\s+","");
char[] letters = cleansed.toCharArray();
for(char c : letters){
    System.out.print(c+" ");
}
```

When I go to the console and do something like,

```
Enter a word : I am entering some word.
```

The output I get on the console is `I` which seems to be dropping all other `String` values after the space.

What am I missing here?

I play around with different methods when there's nothing to do. So right now I just wonder why it's not working as expected.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26931946/540195

Comment: Can't reproduce. Maybe you tested with different content. Although it doesn't work as you expect anyway... Note that NOT all `String.replace*` methods take a *regex*...

Comment: I see you used `replace("\\s+","")` but you mentioned `replaceAll("\\s+","")`

Comment: @DeepakSharma I edited the question. I'm using the latter which is `replaceAll("\\s+","");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `scanner.nextLine()` instead of `scanner.next()`. Also use `word.replaceAll()` instead of `word.replace()`

Here is the working code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        String word = scanner.nextLine();
        String cleansed = word.replace("\\s+","");
        char[] letters = cleansed.toCharArray();
        for(char c : letters){
            System.out.print(c+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
Enter a word: Enter a word : I am entering some word.
E n t e r a w o r d : I a m e n t e r i n g s o m e w o r d .
```

Comment: Thanks. I failed to notice that at first. The code actually comes with other code blocks prior to this which is using the scanner methods `next()`, `nextLine()`. I suspect that the `next()` and `nextLine()` and `nextInt()` methods are getting mixed up since I'm using one `scanner` object.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
String word = scanner.next();
word = word.replaceAll(" ","");
char letters [] = word.toCharArray();
for(char c : letters){
    System.out.print(c+" ");
}
```