# Java program is outputting spaces between variables pulled from main(), which is fine. However I would like to remove the trailing space

Tags: java, methods, double

This is my code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class LabProgram {

    public static double drivingCost(double drivenMiles, double dollarsPerGallon, double milesPerGallon)
    {  double totalCost = 0;
    totalCost = (drivenMiles / milesPerGallon) * dollarsPerGallon ;
    System.out.printf("%.2f", totalCost);
    System.out.print(" ");
    return totalCost;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double milesPGallon;
    double dollarsPGallon;
    double driveMiles;
    double drivingCost;
    milesPGallon = input.nextDouble();
    dollarsPGallon = input.nextDouble();
    input.close();
    drivingCost(10, dollarsPGallon, milesPGallon);
    drivingCost(50, dollarsPGallon, milesPGallon);
    drivingCost(400, dollarsPGallon, milesPGallon);
    System.out.print("\r");
    }
    }
```

The output is: '1.58 7.90 63.20 ' and what I need is '1.58 7.90 63.20'. How can I remove the trailing space in the output? I have tried to use trim() and replace() neither has helped at all. I am new to Java and have been banging my head against the wall for the last day and a half trying to figure this out. Any assistance would be appreciated even if it is just a nudge in the correct direction. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should not be closing the Scanner instance either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing whitespace from strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455794/removing-whitespace-from-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`drivingCost` is printing a space every time you call it:

```
public static double drivingCost(double drivenMiles, double dollarsPerGallon, double milesPerGallon)
{
    double totalCost = 0;
    totalCost = (drivenMiles / milesPerGallon) * dollarsPerGallon ;
    System.out.printf("%.2f", totalCost);
    System.out.print(" "); // <-------- here!
    return totalCost;
}
```

You can remove that line, and instead print a space *between* calls to `drivingCost`:

```
drivingCost(10, dollarsPGallon, milesPGallon);
System.out.print(" ");
drivingCost(50, dollarsPGallon, milesPGallon);
System.out.print(" ");
drivingCost(400, dollarsPGallon, milesPGallon);
```

Alternatively, add an extra parameter to `drivingCost`:

```
public static double drivingCost(double drivenMiles, double dollarsPerGallon, double milesPerGallon, boolean isLastCall)
{
    double totalCost = 0;
    totalCost = (drivenMiles / milesPerGallon) * dollarsPerGallon ;
    System.out.printf("%.2f", totalCost);

    if (!isLastCall) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    return totalCost;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
drivingCost(10, dollarsPGallon, milesPGallon, false);
drivingCost(50, dollarsPGallon, milesPGallon, false);
drivingCost(400, dollarsPGallon, milesPGallon, true);
```

Comment: Let's do this right -- The driving cost method shouldn't be printing anything as a method should have a single purpose and should be without side-effects. Rather let the main get the result from drivingCost and then decide how to use it, including printing what it wants.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Well, what if it were called `printDrivingCost`? I assumed (for my own convenience :P) that this is just a badly named method, and this question is not about how to name methods. Though you can argue that `printDrivingCost` shouldn't do the calculation, I think that's out of the scope of this question. Though doing so is nice, We are not expected to fix every single problem (however small) of OP's code, are we?

Comment: ... unless the printing is being used as a "poor-man's debugger"

Comment: THank you all for the help. It is now outputting the correct format. I appreciate all the time everyone took.

Comment: This also works:    System.out.printf("%.2f ", totalCost);
      totalCost = drivingCost(50, milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon);
      System.out.printf("%.2f ", totalCost);
      totalCost = drivingCost(400, milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon);
      System.out.printf("%.2f", totalCost);
      System.out.println();