# Remove white spaces from the Java string

Tags: java, string

Am trying to remove the spaces from the java string leaving the special characters,...

```
existing: "[Cars]/Info/{​​​​​​​​​      123}​​​​​​​​​    /{4533449​​​​​​​​​      }​     ";
expected: "[Cars]/Info/{​​​​​​​​​123}​​​​​​​​​/{4533449​​​​​​​​​}";
```

Any help would be really appreciated..

Comment: `existing.replace(" ", "")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing whitespace from strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455794/removing-whitespace-from-strings-in-java)

Comment: @YCF_L i tried, but still no luck with this..

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.replace(toReplace, replaceWith)` like so:

```
st.replaceAll("\\s+","")
```

Where `st` is "`[Cars]/Info/{​​​​​​​​​      123}​​​​​​​​​    /{4533449​​​​​​​​​      }​`     "

This:

```
String st = "[Cars]/Info/{​​​​​​​​​      123}​​​​​​​​​    /{4533449​​​​​​​​​      }​     ";
System.out.println(st.replaceAll("\\s+",""));
```

Produces this:

```
[Cars]/Info/{​​​​​​​​​123}​​​​​​​​​/{4533449​​​​​​​​​}​
```

If you want to remove the spaces for the specific variable, use

```
st = st.replaceAll("\\s+","")
```

Comment: Still no luck.. its still not replacing the empty spaces

Comment: @Carsboy It is for me. Please read my answer carefully

Comment: I tried the way above you mentioned but still I'm seeing the spaces in the string..  Am I missing something.. 

st.replaceAll("\\s+","");

Comment: String cleanedCarNumber= (request.getCarNumber());
        log.info("cleaned car number1::"+cleanedCarNumber.replaceAll("\\s+",""));


Logger response: cleaned car number1::[Cars]/Info/{        ​​​​​​​​​123}​​​​​​​​​       /{14163449       ​​​​​​​​​}​

Comment: @Carsboy Please see my edited answer.

Comment: This could be further improved to omit out any non-ASCII chars should they occur:
`st = st.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]*[^\\S]","");`

Comment: There are some non-ASCII chars that can appear like white spaces

Comment: @Carsboy If my answer answers your question, please consider accepting! :)