# Remove spaces using substring

Tags: java, substring, indexoutofboundsexception, removing-whitespace

I have this:

```
private String remove_spaces(String s){
    s = s.trim();
    String updated = "";
    for (int i = 0;  i < s.length(); i++) {
        String tester = s.substring(i, i + 1);
        String space = " ";
        boolean isSpace = tester.equals(space);
        if (isSpace = false)
            updated += tester;
    }
    return updated;
}
```

And it throws an `StringIndexOutOfBounds`, and I don't understand why. Why?

Comment: In Java you can remove spaces using replaceAll
here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455794/removing-whitespace-from-strings-in-java

Comment: @ДөлгөөнМөнхчулуун yep, but there's specified *using* *substring*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got `index out of bounds` error because you are trying to reach an index greater than the actual length of your array

```java
String tester = s.substring(i,i + 1);
```

I suggest an if clause like this

```java
private String remove_spaces(String s) {
    s = s.trim();
    String updated = "";
    String tester = "";
    for (int i = 0;  i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (i != s.length-1) {
            tester = s.substring(i, i + 1);
        }else{
            tester = s.substring(i);
        }
        if (!tester.equals(" ")) {
            updated += tester;
        }
    }
    return updated;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `==` to do comparison while `=` is substitution operator.

```
if (isSpace == false)
```

Additionally, you can use `!`(=not) to shorten your code like below:

```
private String remove_spaces(String s) {
    s = s.trim();
    String updated = "";
    for (int i = 0;  i < s.length(); i++) {
        String tester = s.substring(i, i + 1);
        if (!tester.equals(" ")) {
            updated += tester;
        }
    }
    return updated;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way to remove spaces in your String in Java would be

```
str = str.replace(" ","");
```

But if you want something similar to your code, try the below one, I guess **substring** is not needed we can use **charAt** for that.

```
private static String remove_spaces(String s) {
    s = s.trim();
    StringBuilder updated = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0;  i < s.length(); i++) {
      Character tester = s.charAt(i);
      if (!tester.equals(' ')) {
        updated.append(tester);
      }
    }
    return updated.toString();
  }
```